# Is there a command in which we can see list of shared directories and with whom they are shared for windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, network-shares

Is there a command in which we can see list of shared directories and **with whom they are shared for** Windows 7? I have tried the below commands:

```
net share    
wmic share get caption,name,path
```

But I can't get the names of the people or entity with **whom** they are shared.

Comment: `for /F %G in ('net share^|find /i /v "The com"') do net share %G` (a basic hint only, should be improved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I get a list of shared directories (and whom they are shared with)?

`net session` will give you the information you are looking for.

---

#### Net session

> Manages server computer connections. Used without parameters, net
>   session displays information about all sessions with the local
>   computer.
>
> Syntax
>
> `net session [\\ComputerName] [/delete]`
>
> Parameters
>
> `\\ComputerName`   : Identifies the computer for which you want to
>   list or disconnect sessions.

...

> **Use net session** to view the computer names and user names of users on
>   a server, **to see if users have files open**, and to see how long each
>   user's session has been idle.
>
> The information appears in a format similar to the following:
>
> ```
> Computer      User name        Client type  Opens   Idle time
> -------------------------------------------------------------
> \\BASSETT     CHRISDR          Windows 2000   1     00:00:13
> \\SHARONCA    Administrator    DOS LM 2.1     0     01:05:13
> ```
>
> **To display one user's session, use ComputerName with the command. The
>   information about a single user includes a list of shared resources to
>   which the user has connections.**

Source [Net session](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490711.aspx)

---

#### Disconnect a user or users

> For example, to disconnect a user on a computer named user_computer,
>   which is connected to a shared folder that you are managing, type:
>
> ```
> net session \\user_computer /delete
> ```

...

Syntax:

`net session \\<computer> /delete`

where:

> - `Net session`   **Lists** or disconnects **users connected to shared folders on the computer**.
> - `\\<computer>`  The name of the computer accessing the shared folder.
> - `/delete`       Ends the session, and closes all open files on the computer for the session. If you omit \computer, the command ends the sessions on the local computer.

Source [Disconnect a User](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725598.aspx)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [net](http://ss64.com/nt/net.html)  - The NET Command is used to manage network resources.