# Map shared printer to LPT port returns "no more connections can be made to this remote computer"

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, network-printer

I have a computer running Windows 10 Enterprise. This computers shares a printer, so that when I'm connected to my server I can print to there by mapping it to a LPT port using the following command:

```
NET USE LPT1 \\MY-COMPUTER\MY-PRINTER /PERSISTENT:YES
```

So far it was working great, but suddently I started to receive the following message when using the above command:

> System error 71 has occurred.
>
> No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept.

Searching around I've found that this is a common problem when using Remote Desktop Services or mapping a shared folder, but none of the solutions I found were helpful.

So, what I want to know is:

- Is there any way I can increase the limit of "simultaneos" connections?
- Is there any way I can manage the existing connections and maybe disconnect some of the users so others can connect (without going machine by machine and running `NET USE ... /delte`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are built-in limitations in non-server Windows versions,
obviously to encourage users to buy server licenses.
One of them is no more than 10 concurrent connections to a remote computer.

I list below some solutions:

- Upgrade to a Windows Server license
- Use Linux with Samba as printer server
- Use several computers to share the files/printers
- Decrease the timeout period for user connections, to close unused connections faster (default 15 minutes). The following will set it to one minute:

  ```
  net config server /autodisconnect:1
  ```

  This is mostly for shared folders but may apply to printers.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Is there a (centralized) way to manage the connected clients and maybe disconnect them to free up some slots?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/897257/8672